# apt-get doesn't work as expected within bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, debian

I have small script in bash which automates installation of a few packages. It installs a few packages using apt-get and the rest from sources. I have all the sources I need tarred into a single tar file. The sample script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get install wget gcc g++ ruby php5 php5-dev xz-utils bzip2 -y

cd /usr/local/bin/
wget my-sources.tar.gz
tar zxvf my-sources.tar.gz
cd my-sources

tar zxvf package1.tar.gz
cd package1
./configure && make && make install

cd /usr/local/src/my-sources
tar zxvf package2.tar.gz
cd package2
./configure && make && make install

cd /usr/local/src/my-sources
tar zxvf package3.tar.gz
cd package3
./configure && make && make install

echo -e "\nFinished\n"
```

This script is then encoded using `zlib` in python 2.7:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import zlib

with open("/usr/local/src/sample.sh") as inputfile:
    teststr = zlib.compress(inputfile.read()).encode('base64')
    print teststr
```

This is then passed to a python script which executes it as follows:

```
thisstr = "Gu11nX1eVdeGlaMoouIyJtOV/cPBWrp1b7OeY7P7GXtzb
x7HETWRhTHC6NzM3k0nH6dw8uFs+qRtkJWiPrBGs1mlXWJjt7ZSUHe0
ZougLFsrAmxs3b+l+q9UKFrL1aAt0glTEo8bUuSO7Gjfe3JaYpedEgt
qkbZtz825OWUlyiz+pMPmkOdlhYu2ia+at+ZJIGZRkFzsBIqJKNhAQ4
LlBdMzdGu593UzCBtsspZiVntsFlzbyefpjCBk+PDKbyefOZMPy9Xd/
wL3ieojA=="
str=zlib.decompress(thisstr.decode('base64'))

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as scriptfile:
    scriptfile.write(str)
    scriptfile.flush()
    subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name])
```

What happens here is, while `apt-get` is being executed, in-between, the `wget` is attempted. Since `wget` isn't installed yet, the wget command fails and then the execution moves to the compiling and building steps (which throw errors as the files aren't available). All the while, the `apt-get` is still being executed.

I tried 2 steps to avoid this:

- Added `sleep 5` at the end of the `apt-get` command. This did not
  help.
- Put `apt-get` in another function and called the function just
  before the `wget` command.

this too did not help.

Of course, when I run it the second time, the packages get installed (because all the packages to be installed using `apt-get` are already there).

This was tested and is for Debian 6/Debian 7

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Have you tried putting `wait` after the `apt-get`?

Comment: @lifesaspanner - No, I was unaware of such an option. Could you give the syntax for the `wait` so that I can try it out?

Comment: It's just `wait`. Just type it on the line after `apt-get`. Have a look at `man wait` for reference.

Comment: @lifesaspanner - nope. Din't work. Same error.

Comment: Does the script work as planned when you execute it straight from a shell? What about from python but without the compression?

Comment: @DanielLandau - when I it without the compression (i.e when i run the bash script alone),it works as expected.

Comment: what happens if you run the decoded script manually from bash (don't write it to a tempfile but to a persistent file, then run it)?

Comment: This is a real strange one, as shell scripts should run in a linear manner, not parallel. I'm wondering. Do you get the same problem if you `apt-get` each package one at a time, instead of passing all the packages to one `apt-get` command? Also, does adding `shell=True` to the end of the call (i.e. `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name], shell=True)`) help at all?

Comment: @lifesaspanner putting `shell=True` is unhelpful, and in fact potentially harmful, here: It tells Python to use a shell to start the shell that runs the script, as opposed to having only a single shell involved. If the script's filename includes characters which a shell can interpret, then that extra shell can cause bugs.

Comment: @lifesaspanner ...in terms of `wait`, it only has any effect when job control has been used for backgrounding. First, there's no `&` on the preceding line. Second, job control is turned off by default in noninteractive shells.

Comment: The base64 string given in the question not valid. Thus, the code in question cannot be a correct reproducer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this workflow with my own script and everything works fine for me, although decoding/decompressing the string you provide fails with `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`.

The only suggestions I can make are:

1. Put and `r` before the string to make it raw format - the base64 format encoding could create escape sequences (although this is not a problem for the string you provided).
2. Print your `str` decoded string variable - does this match the original script? If there was an `&` at the end of the apt-get line, this would produce the behaviour you describe.
3. Find what happens when you try the call with the original script ie

   `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '/usr/local/src/sample.sh'])`

   If this produces the same behaviour, check if it still happens running the script directly from bash. It could be some oddity that python introduces or some issue with the bash/apt configuration that causes things to go into the background (although I have no idea of any option that could do that and I know both fairly well).